# Create an infinite background wave pattern

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, sketch-app, patterns

I need to adjust this background wave image to an infinite pattern.

When the background repeats in the x direction the lines need to be integrated in a way that only looks like a single image, not like the image below.

[image]

I have the [.sketch](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3iwlaut5j6nqyc3/waves.sketch?dl=0) of this file. Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: I had to select the wave lines and go to **Object > Path > Outline Stroke**. Otherwise when using the shape tool the wave got distorted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Create a horizontal line and apply a **ZigZag Effect**: **Menu Effect** > **Distort & Transform** > **Zig Zag**

[image: ZIG ZAG]

- **Menu Object** > **Expand Appearance**
- Preserve this line and duplicate it twice
- Place those two copies horizontally, contacting the end point of
  one with the beginning of the other
- Select those points with the **Direct Selection Tool** and join them: **Menu Object** > **Path** > **Join**

[image: path]

- Make several copies of the linked line and center the original line on top

[image: lines]

- Create a rectangle the same width as the original line

[image: rectangle]

- Copy the rectangle, and selecting it with a line, use the **Shape Builder Tool** pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> to delete the surplus traces

[image: waves]

- Select the *New Shape*, fill it with a color and add a transparency percentage
- **Menu Edit** > **Paste in Front** to recover the rectangle and repeat with another line

**Result**

[image: waves]

[image: repetition]